# Can you enable IPv6 anycast on a Microsoft DNS server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6

I have an anycast address assigned to a Windows 2012R2 server and I can ping it from across subnets.

The DNS service doesn't see it as an address it can listen on and nslookup (from the server itself) returns "No response from server".

I've tried `dnscmd /ResetListenAddresses` but it won't accept the anycast address.

Does Microsoft DNS support anycast addresses?

Comment: I can't imagine why this wouldn't work. What is the address? Why won't the service listen on it?

Comment: In my case, the address is fd53::1 but it could be any unicast address. Why it won't listen is what I'm trying to figure out. The Interfaces dialog box (in the DNS configuration) doesn't list this address but the server itself responds to it.

Comment: What makes any unicast address an anycast address is that the route to it is advertised from multiple places in the network. The network routing will direct the requester to the "nearest" host with that address. Have you placed any routes for this address or subnet into your routers so that they know it exists on this and the other, network segments?

Comment: Also, `fd53::1` doesn't follow the rules for [Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193#section-3.2.1) since it doesn't have a randomly generated Global ID. It may be that the DNS is not liking that.